# Retrieve issues in JIRA in a plugin

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve issues in a JIRA plugin using the REST API, but when I supply authentication information, it logs me in as that user afterwards.  I would like to retrieve an issue without having to change users.  Here is my AJAX:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://jdev.tmaxlaunch.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=cf[10201]=" + id,
            //headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxx' },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                //console.log(data.issues);
                //console.log(data.issues[0]);
                for (i = 0; i < data.issues.length; i++){
                     console.log(data.issues[i].id);
                     AJS.$('.activity-chart').append('<p>' + data.issues[i].fields.summary + '</p>');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr,textStatus,err)
            {
                console.log("readyState: " + xhr.readyState);
                console.log("responseText: "+ xhr.responseText);
                console.log("status: " + xhr.status);
                console.log("text status: " + textStatus);
                console.log("error: " + err);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What's your use case? Why are you switching users on the client side, and/or why do you need to deauthenticate?

Comment: I want to send the authorization header based on the current user's login information without them having to input it every time I want to make this ajax call

Comment: I don't quite follow. The question suggests that you don't want to remain logged on as a specific user. But the comment above suggests that you do want to remain logged in. You also wrote about not having to "change" users. Are you logging in as multiple users from the client side? (Why?) And perhaps could you handle some of this authentication-switching from the server side of your plugin?

Comment: This ajax call requires authorization or login information. But multiple users will be using the page that makes this ajax call.  So if I put static login information in the ajax call headers, it will switch whichever user accesses this page to the user used in the ajax call header.

Comment: On the server side, what about creating your own REST endpoint that applies the [correct user authentication context](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/6.2.1/com/atlassian/jira/security/JiraAuthenticationContext.html) to your request, and then calling that instead of the public JQL API? This avoids your having to expose any additional credentials to the end user at all.

Comment: I guess that would work, unless there is a better way, I might have to do that.

Comment: There is also [OAuth](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+OAuth+authentication), but that suffers from the same problem of exposing credentials (even if only in the form of an OAuth token) that would allow the client to do anything that the underlying user has permissions to do.